# Trying to make a write function for a class and getting error

Tags: c++

I have implemented a write function for my class but iam getting error:

```
class Fa{
private:
  string Q_;
  string F_;

public:
   void write(ostream& out = cout) const{
   out<<Q_<<endl;
   out<<F_<<endl;
   }
};
```

> Error:default argument given for parameter 1 of `void Fa::write(std::ostream&) const'

Can anybody please tell me what does this error mean and how could i avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing includes and namespaces:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Fa{
  private:
    std::string Q_;
    std::string F_;

  public:
    void write(std::ostream& out = std::cout) const{
      out << Q_<< std::endl;
      out << F_<< std::endl;
    }
};
```

If you have a header and a cpp file, in the header file specify the default argument:

```
  /* ... */
  public:
    void write(std::ostream& out = std::cout) const;
  /* ... */
```

and in the cpp file do not:

```
    void Fa::write(std::ostream& out) const {
       /* ... */
    }
```

Comment: Even when i added using std::string;
using std::ostream;
using std::cout;
using std::endl; which i haven't before, iam still getting the same error.

Comment: which argument u r talking about

Comment: As i did what u have said i'am getting this errors:  [Linker error] undefined reference to `operator<<(std::ostream&, Fa::Transition const&)'

Comment: this is not really related. You are using `<<` operator for Transition type without having an overload. you need smt like `std::ostream &operator << (std::ostream &out, const Fa::Transition const&) { /* ... */ }` see: http://lifecs.likai.org/2010/10/c-overloading-operator-for-stdostream.html